# CSS transforms won't apply on page load and dynamically update on <g> inside svg

Tags: html, css, svg, transform

I wanted to position text in the bottom left of an SVG element, and managed to achieve that using groups and transforms, but noticed that it won't update if i resize my window vertically, and also it won't apply on page load, but if i add the transform properties through developer console. they work perfectly, until i resize the window.

Is it some kind of a bug or i am doing something wrong? Is there another way to position text inside SVG element relative to bottom left and keep it responsive to window resize? I am using chrome 61 by the way.

here's a link to jsfiddle too:
https://jsfiddle.net/eow1c4o4/

```css
*,*:before,*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 300vh
}
tspan {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 50px;
  dominant-baseline: hanging;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100vh">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
      <g style="transform: translate(0, 100%);">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
        <g style="transform: translate(50px, -100%);">
          <text x="0" y="0" text-anchor="start" font-family="Roboto">
            <tspan x="0" dy="0">SOME</tspan>
            <tspan x="0" dy="0.81em">ABSOLUTELY</tspan>
            <tspan x="0" dy="0.81em">RANDOM TEXT</tspan>
          </text>
        </g>
      </g>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#dedede" fill-rule="evenodd" mask="url(#mask)"></rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Transforms in SVGs don't allow percentages.  But geometric attributes do allow them. So the simplest way to do this is with a `<use>` element.

```css
*,*:before,*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 300vh
}
tspan {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100vh">
  <defs>
    <text id="mytext" x="0" y="-80" text-anchor="start" font-family="Roboto">
      <tspan x="0" dy="0">SOME</tspan>
      <tspan x="0" dy="0.81em">ABSOLUTELY</tspan>
      <tspan x="0" dy="0.81em">RANDOM TEXT</tspan>
    </text>
    <mask id="mask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
      <use xlink:href="#mytext" x="5%" y="95%" fill="black"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#dedede" fill-rule="evenodd" mask="url(#mask)"></rect>
</svg>
```

The way we get the text to sit at the bottom, is to initially position it just off the top of the screen. Then we use a `<use>` element to reposition it at `y="95%"`. That's just a little less than 100% so it ends up just above the bottom.

https://jsfiddle.net/eow1c4o4/1/